# Write Decimal numbers in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

In need to write the number 7.2 in a table field.
What type the field needs to be.
And what type needs the variable to be?

Comment: You could use one of many different data types. Rather, the question is, to which set of values (domain) does your value '7.2' belong?

Comment: @onedaywhen then you very much for your interest. It is the truth that i have solve my issue with another way, which i found it not professional. So thats why I'm looking the right answer.

Comment: Erm, so tell us the domain. For example, if the domain is the Dewey Decimal System then `DECIMAL(2,1)` would be the wrong answer.

Comment: @onedaywhen I really can't undrestand why you driving into the DDC (which is an issue far away from what i ask). And yes the DECIMAL (2,1) will not work as far as i tested. The best practice is DECIMAL (3,2) and has two digits before comma and one digit after. And that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 has a `DECIMAL` type which works quite well.

You can define a precision (total number of digits) and a scale (number of digits after the decimal separator).

- `DECIMAL(2,1)` would be: two digits, one of which after the separator (one before)
- `DECIMAL(5,2)` would be: five figits total, two of which after the separator (three before)

See [DECIMAL and NUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) in SQL Server Books Online for more details

In .NET, this would be a type `decimal` as well.

Comment: Dear @marc_s thank you for your answer but i'm facing few issues which i can't understand. In order to convert my number from my TextBox i use this: Dim veM100 As Decimal = TextBox1.Text. And i'm taking veM100 = 72D (my number is 7.2). I use in SQL Decimal(3,2) and the number which is writed is 72.00. this is complitelly out of my willing. Please assist me

Comment: Finally i solve my issue by using the following: Dim veM100 As String = TextBox1.Text. When tha goes to the table is turned in 7.2. Thank you very much.